# How to correctly send POST request like there?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

How to correctly send POST request like this?

The screenshot of the correct post response
[image]

As you can see all the lines in the right places.

There is screenshot of my response(not correctly):
[image]

As you can see all the strings are arranged in a single row.

There is my code (Delphi):

```
 procedure TForm1.sButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Data : TStringList;
  l,p:string;
html:string;
begin
HTTP:=TIdHTTP.Create(self);
Data := TStringList.Create;

HTTP.HandleRedirects:=True;
HTTP.Request.Host:='192.168.0.111';
HTTP.Request.Connection:='keep-alive';
HTTP.Request.CacheControl:='max-age=0';
HTTP.Request.Accept:='text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
HTTP.Request.UserAgent:='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36';
HTTP.Request.AcceptLanguage:='ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4';
//-----------
HTTP.Request.Referer:='http://192.168.0.111/';
HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
  with HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders do
  begin
    AddValue('Cookie','Authorization=Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=');
  end;
http.Get('http://192.168.0.111/');
HTTP.Request.ContentType:='text/plain';
HTTP.Request.Accept:='text/plain';
Data.Add('[WAN_ETH_INTF#2,0,0,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]0,2');
Data.Add('enable');
Data.Add('X_TP_lastUsedIntf');
Data.Add('[WAN_IP_CONN#2,1,1,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]1,0');
Data.Add('[WAN_IP_CONN#2,1,2,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]2,0');
Data.Add('[WAN_PPP_CONN#2,1,1,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]3,0');
Data.Add('[WAN_IP6_CONN#2,1,1,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]4,0');
Data.Text:=URLDecode(Data.Text);
html:=HTTP.Post('http://192.168.0.111/cgi?1&1&1&1&1',Data);
sMemo1.Lines.Add(html);;
Data.Free;
FreeAndNil(HTTP);
end;
```

How to make correctly response in my situation?

Comment: Remove `Data.Text:=URLDecode(Data.Text);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `URLDecode()` is complete wrong.  Get rid of it.

That being said, you are using the version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` that is meant for submitting an HTML webform in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.  `Post()` will encode the `TStringList` data accordingly.  That is what you are seeing in your screenshot, but that is not what you want in this situation.  To send your string data as-is, line breaks and all, you need to save your data to a `TStream` instead and then `Post()` that.  It will be transmitted as-is without any encoding.

Also, this code looks suspiciously wrong, too:

```
with HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders do
begin
  AddValue('Cookie','Authorization=Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=');
end;
```

Are you sure you are supposed to be sending a `Cookie` header? That look more like it should be an `Authentication` header instead:

```
AddValue('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=');
```

If so, `TIdHTTP` has built-in support for `Basic` authentication, you should not be using `CustomHeaders` for a `Authentication: Basic ...` header at all:

```
HTTP.Request.Username := 'admin';
HTTP.Request.Password := 'admin';
HTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
```

Try this instead:

```
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Data: TMemoryStream;
  html:string;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    HTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    HTTP.Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';
    HTTP.Request.CacheControl := 'max-age=0';
    HTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
    HTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36';
    HTTP.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4';
    //-----------
    HTTP.Request.Referer := 'http://192.168.0.111/';

    //HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Cookie','Authorization=Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=');
    HTTP.Request.Username := 'admin';
    HTTP.Request.Password := 'admin';
    HTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;

    // you are calling the version of TIdHTTP.Get() that returns
    // the response data as a String, but you are ignoring that
    // data in this first request. You can optionally reduce some
    // memory usage and increase performance by telling Get() that
    // you do not want any response data returned to you. TIdHTTP
    // will still read it but silently discard it...
    //
    // HTTP.Get('http://192.168.0.111/', TStream(nil));
    HTTP.Get('http://192.168.0.111/');

    Data := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/plain';
      HTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/plain';
      WriteStringToStream(Data, '[WAN_ETH_INTF#2,0,0,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]0,2'+EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(Data, 'enable'+EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(Data, 'X_TP_lastUsedIntf'+EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(Data, '[WAN_IP_CONN#2,1,1,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]1,0'+EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(Data, '[WAN_IP_CONN#2,1,2,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]2,0'+EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(Data, '[WAN_PPP_CONN#2,1,1,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]3,0'+EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(Data, '[WAN_IP6_CONN#2,1,1,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]4,0'+EOL);
      Data.Position := 0;
      html := HTTP.Post('http://192.168.0.111/cgi?1&1&1&1&1', Data);
      sMemo1.Lines.Add(html);
    finally
      Data.Free;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```